# How to access variables in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a function to validate user entered password. It contains regular expression along with conditions.

conditions are

1. Password should be more than 8 and less than 14
2. Password should contain atleast a number.

Now my question, I want to pass those min and max numbers dynamically to regular expression

snippet, what I was trying :

```
function validatePassword(plain,minmaxValues) {
  const passwordChecker = /^(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{minmaxValues.min,minmaxValues.max}$/;
  return passwordChecker.test(plain);
}
```

When I debug, I can see `passwordChecker` value is not updating with `minmaxValues`.

will be appreciate, if anyone can help.

Thanks

Comment: Use a RegExp constructor and juts concat the variables with string literals.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. It's working